# Can't import package in python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-3.5

I have installed python3.5 on my server. I installed `pysher` with pip3, everything works fine, in python3.5 terminal, I can use `import pysher` without error. Now, I develop script, where is some python3.6 features, so I installed python3.6 on my server and now, I am not able to `import pysher` in python3.6 terminal:

```
>>> import pysher
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysher'
```

So I tried install pysher again:

```
# pip3 install pysher
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install python3-pip
```

Even when I konw I have installed python3-pip, I tried it agian:

```
# apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 138 not upgraded.
```

Of course, I can rewrite my second script to work with python3.5, but I am curious why it is not working and how to repair it.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
dpkg -L python3-pip | grep bin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/pip3

export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/pip3"
pip3 search pysher
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install python3-pip
```

This did not work, so I try get version of pip3:

```
# /usr/bin/pip3 --version
-bash: /usr/bin/pip3: No such file or directory
```

pip3 is not in `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: @mike.k have you read it?

Comment: How did you install python 3.6? It may have overwritten your system python2.

Comment: Hi, I installed it via `apt-get install python3.6`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `dpkg -L python3-pip` to find out where `apt` installed your `pip3`. Then

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/mypippath`

Will add it to your path. After that, try`pip3` again.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to work with pip files.

1 - Inside of a program file like this :

```
import pip
pip.main(["install" , "package"])
```

2 - Getting into the scripts folder in Python directory and command line and printing the following content :

```
C:\Python\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install package
```

Comment: HI, this could help, I tried to `search package` and `--version` of pip, it works fine, but do not solve my problem. I can't install package from program every time.